# Embedding jetty for Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, embedded-jetty

I have a file transfer routing developed in Apache camel. I want to embed Jetty server into this project so that i can keep the service running without deploying it to another server. It will be really helpful if someone can put some code.

Thank You.

Comment: Check this resource http://blog.kopis.de/2015/06/14/microservices-with-apache-camel/ maybe it will answer your needs. However - maybe you should be clear what do you mean by "project".

Comment: Are you asking how to run this as a stand-alone program driven from it's main()?  i.e., as described on this Camel page: 
http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Camel's Jetty component](https://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) and declare a consumer, which will automatically bring up an embedded Jetty:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:{{port}}/myapp/myservice")
    .process(new MyProcessor());
```

Comment: Where will you deploy this code ? I mean how will you run this code ? His ultimate question is that :)

Comment: The question was how to include an embedded Jetty into a Camel project, not how to run or deploy it.

Comment: May be I interpreted it wrongly by reading this statement - ' so that i can keep the service running without deploying it to another server'

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options, they are quite popular:

1. Use maven camel:run plugin, you have to just enable this in your pom file and run the command. (I am not too sure whether they use Jetty internally, but it works)
2. Spring boot, Its quite easy to create a project nowadays, using the web portal.
3. There is one more maven plugin as well for Jetty , which is mvn jetty:run

Comment: It's bad practice to use your build system to run your application in production.

Comment: Yeah but it also depends on how it is used. There are projects which uses this option in production , it depends on the sensitivity of the use case and how it is executed, That's why I have mentioned Spring boot as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've also seen systems with DB tables with a million records with and no primary keys or indexes for any of the queries. The fact that someone chooses to accept a bad design and adopt a bad practice approach should never mean that it's okay to promote that kind of behavior :) And while Spring Boot and Camel make for an awesome combo, just running Camel with Spring Boot does not allow you to embed Jetty into your app.

Comment: I certainly agree with your point with the DB tables example. But not with maven plugin for camel. It gives me this advantage: 1. Run a integration flow purely open source, which means I dont have to pay for any server license or production support cost 2. Its just a less sophisticated runtime, thats all. You can always write some scripts, to keep up the server even if it crashes for some reason. Certainly, its not a good idea to run it production if its going to deal with some critical financial transaction, but its a great option for a simple file based use case.

Comment: And yes, like mentioned in the article from Gabriel, this maven plugin option will work great with docker :)

Comment: Let me just illustrate the many levels of wrongness that your approach incurs: 1) You wouldn't have to pay for an executable JAR file anyhow - you'd just build it and deploy it 2) It's not just a less sophisticated runtime - it requires your production servers to have several dependencies they do not need - your production must use JDK instead of JRE, must have Maven and Git installed, must know where you host your code, must first check out the appropriate version of your source code, compile it and only then run it, and you have to do this for every single instance of your service.

Comment: And every single extra step is a possible point of failure. The reason people developed CI servers is to avoid just doing the kind of thing you suggest.